# Moq fails to throw specific exception in Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have an Azure function that stores applications settings in Azure Blob Storage. To unit test the class that gets and adds the settings, I use moq to have the blob storage abstraction class (blobStorageRepository) throw an exception. It mostly works. however, I have two tests that fail.

I Have other unit tests that mocks the _blobStorageRepository. I have two different unit tests that uses moc to throw a specfic exception (StorageException) and I have set the moq up to throw that exception, but the moq always throw a normal "exception".

The method I'm testing is in a base class and the test is calling a class that uses the base class.

Here the test:

```
        [Fact(DisplayName = "SystemSettingsRepository - Add StorageException")]
        [Trait("Category", "Unit Test")]
        public async Task AddSettingsAsyncTestBaseClassWithStorageException()
        {
            string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            string body = File.ReadAllText("TestData/systemSettings.json");
            SystemSettingsObject systemSettingsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SystemSettingsObject>(body);

            var iFunctionEnvironment = TestHelpers.GetEnvironmentVariable("Test");

            var iblobStorageRepositoryMoq = new Mock<IBlobStorageRepository>();
            iblobStorageRepositoryMoq
                .Setup(mock => mock.Add(It.IsAny<ILogger>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ThrowsAsync(new StorageException("Function Add threw an exception"));
            var iblobStorageRepository = iblobStorageRepositoryMoq.Object;

            SystemSettingsRepository systemSettingsRepository = new SystemSettingsRepository(iFunctionEnvironment, iblobStorageRepository);

            Exception exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<StorageException>(async () => await systemSettingsRepository.Add(logger, correlationId, id, systemSettingsObject));
            Assert.Equal($"Function Add threw an exception", exception.Message);
            Assert.Null(exception.InnerException);
```

And here's the interface for the base class:

```
    {
        Task<bool> Add(ILogger logger, string correlationId, string id, TEntity entity);
    }
```

Here's the implementation of the class:

```
    {        
        private readonly BlobStorageConfiguration _blobStorageConfiguration;

        private readonly IFunctionEnvironment _functionEnvironment;
        private readonly IBlobStorageRepository _blobStorageRepository;

        public Repository(IFunctionEnvironment functionEnvironment,
                          IBlobStorageRepository blobStorageRepository)
        {
            _functionEnvironment = functionEnvironment;
            _blobStorageRepository = blobStorageRepository;

            ConfigReader configurationReader = new ConfigReader(_functionEnvironment);

            // blobStorageConfiguration = configurationReader.BlobStorageConfiguration;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Add(ILogger logger, string correlationId, string id, TEntity entity)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(correlationId))
            {
                correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {

                throw new ArgumentException("Argument id is missing or empty");
            }

            if (entity == null)
            {

                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }

            try
            {
                string settingsObjectString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);

                bool response = await _blobStorageRepository.Add(logger, correlationId, settingsObjectString, id);
                return response;
            }
            catch (StorageException storageException)
            {

                throw new StorageException(storageException.Message, storageException.InnerException);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                throw new InvalidOperationException($"settingsObject upload {id} failed", exception.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the interface to the class using the above base class:

```
public interface ISystemSettingsRepository : IRepository<SystemSettingsObject>
    {
    }
```

And here's the implementation of that class:

```
public class SystemSettingsRepository : Repository<SystemSettingsObject>, ISystemSettingsRepository
    {        
        private readonly BlobStorageConfiguration _blobStorageConfiguration;

        private readonly IFunctionEnvironment _functionEnvironment;
        private readonly IBlobStorageRepository _blobStorageRepository;

        public SystemSettingsRepository(IFunctionEnvironment functionEnvironment,
                                        IBlobStorageRepository blobStorageRepository) : base(functionEnvironment,
                                                                                             blobStorageRepository)
        {            
            _functionEnvironment = functionEnvironment;
            _blobStorageRepository = blobStorageRepository;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to get the mock to throw other exception types, e.g. InvalidOperationException, but the moq only throws an "ordinary" exception. I do have other unit tests, where I not using the interface/Base class setup, and there the moq throws the exception, I have set up.

Ideas and suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Ok I'll see if I can reproduce that.

Comment: Tested and moq returns the expected exception of the desired type that was given to it.

Comment: I get this: ```    Assert.Throws() Failure
    Expected: typeof(Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException)
    Actual:   typeof(System.InvalidOperationException): settingsObject upload 87c2a47d-8f47-46c4-8fa8-bfde42b2038d failed
    ---- System.InvalidOperationException : settingsObject upload 87c2a47d-8f47-46c4-8fa8-bfde42b2038d failed ```

Comment: Step through the subject method while debugging and see what is the actual exception thrown before you wrap it in the `InvalidOperationException` Should give an idea as to what is the true cause. I suspect again that the mock was invoked with something different to what was setup.

Comment: This is strange. When stepping through the code, I can see that the moq actually throws the right exception: Exception thrown: 
    Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll  But that get caught by the "method under test" handler for Exception

Comment: Ok let me see if I can reproduce that.

Comment: Made a test and the correct exception is being caught.

Comment: Check example code of working test https://dotnetfiddle.net/pEoHMC

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your using in your classes, i had this same error, but i was using different references. That way, the exceptions are really different.